# Is there a way to achieve implicit type cast or conversion in java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I wanted to create a method that takes an `enum` and uses it directly in an computation

```
  private static int getEntries(List<Integer> vector, Sign sign)
  {
    //assert isPrimitiveTypeCompliant(vector) : "Vector has null components!";
    int entries = 0;

    for (Integer entry : vector)
      if (entry * sign > 0) // does not compile
        entries++;

    return entries;
  }
```

I thought sth. like that was possible, since I assumed `System.out.println(Object)` does implicit type conversion, too. Which it doesn't, it uses following approach:

```
 public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        synchronized (this) {
            print(s);
            newLine();
        }
    }

 public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

**Question**

So is it possible to achieve this in java? Or is this reserved to `C++` and overloading of operators? What are the common workarounds? Utility/Adapter classes that do the work?

---

Btw, I eventually ended up with this approach

```
  private enum Sign
  {
    POSITIVE(+1), NEGATIVE(-1);

    private int sign;

    private Sign(int sign)
    {
      this.sign = sign;
    }

    public int process(int n)
    {
      if (n * sign > 0)
      {
        return n;
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }

  private static int getEntries(List<Integer> vector, Sign sign)
  {
    //assert isPrimitiveTypeCompliant(vector) : "Vector has null components";
    int entries = 0;

    for (Integer entry : vector)
      entries += sign.process(entry);

    return entries;
  }
```

Comment: `sign.ordinal()` is an option.

Comment: I think Josh Bloch wrote that a normal developer should never rely on the `ordinal()` function. But I forgot the exact reasons.

Comment: An enum is basically a Set, not a List.  Sets are not intrinsically ordered, and other developers will tend to re-order them.  In fact, they do!!!

Comment: The reason is that if you use ordinals, then when you extend the enum, you can only add values at the end, never in the middle or elsewhere, or else you break everything that depended on the ordinal. This was a hard-learned experience at work, where for a while we stored ordinals in database tables, etc. This made the code much, much less flexible than it should have been. We have now committed not to use ordinals for new code.

Comment: See?  What did I say?

Comment: @MarioRossi You bet. Ordinals were widely used at the time I started at the company, and I had to go around to explain to a number of people why that was a terrible idea. Not only does it prohibit adding values anywhere except at the end, but when you have multiple branches that you have to merge (that add new values to the same enum), at least one of them is guaranteed to break the "add at the end" rule.

Comment: Ouch.  I never thought of the problem with branch merging, and am very happy I never encountered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve it.  In fact, you did in the second piece of code.

Java doesn't have operator overloading or implicit conversions (beyond numerical conversions and "widening" type casts).  So, there is no way of allowing syntax like `entry * sign` (except the one you used).

What do you mean workarounds?  This is not a problem.  It is a language design decision.  And you already arrived successfully to the appropriate Java idiom.

Comment: Yes, the unboxing of `Integer` to `int`. Okay, clear answer. Thought maybe there was more.

Comment: Have you come across the idioms to implement closures/lambda expressions?  This is **nothing**!  It's so bad, that a much better support is coming soon.  I don't think it will ever be the case for enums / operator overloading / implicit conversions because either the idioms are relatively simple or/and the impact of the required changes is too deep.

Comment: Functional programming is the right catchphrase here. What I needed in my example, was just a simple `map` function. ...You mean the ones in java 8 are bad? They're still verbose, but I have not taken a close enough look.

Comment: But let's not be unfair with Java.  For an almost-20-year old language, the contexts it executes in (from servers to smartcards), and the paradigm shifts we have seen, Java has broken extremely few lines of code.  This has always been a critical language design criterion, and I'm sure companies appreciate it.

Comment: No, I meant Java 7.  Java 8 is what's "coming soon" and a **huge** improvement.

Comment: Which paradigm shifts do you mean in particular? From from procedural to OOP? Or that java tries to incoroporate parts of functional programming now? ...I don't know much about history... (But some biology...^^)

Comment: Perhaps "paradigm shift" is an overstatement.  But yes, procedural to OOP to OOP+functional.  And also binary/flat files to XML/JSon.  Text-based to (traditional) graphical to HTML user interfaces. Database sharing to DCE/CORBA to Web Services to Cloud Services.  Thin-client to fat-client to a new kind of thin-client.  I'm probably missing quite a few.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use the int value of the `sign`

```
if (entry * sign.value > 0)



enum Sign

    public final int value;
```

Comment: It's preferable to introduce explicit attributes.  Conceptually (or at least for a majority of developers), enum constants should not be dependent on declaration order.  And they **will** re-order them!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think for this case it would work better for you to use final static variables.

```
public final class Sign {
    public final static int POSITIVE = 1;
    public final static int NEGATIVE = -1;

    private Sign() {
    }
}
```

Then you can use `Sign.POSITIVE` and `Sign.NEGATIVE` for the operations you want.